# How to set JDBC mappings in spring boot JPA project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've a postgres table t1 which has column types like uuid & timestamp with zone etc. which are causing

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

If I try to get d columns which are of types int or varchar, my code works fine, but when I try to include the columns of data type uuid or date type, it fails with the above exception.

So I've a repository interface class which extends my CustomRepository interface which is again implemented by another class to implement my custom queries like below:

```
@Repository
interface Repo extends JpaRepository<Entity, UUID>, CustomRepo {
    // some repo methods
}

interface CustomRepo {
    List queryBy(Type1 par1, Type2 par2);
}

@Service
class CustomRepoImpl implements CustomRepo {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List queryBy(Type1 par1, Type2 par2) {
        query_string = "SOME QUERY STRING WITH JOINS";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query_string);
        List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList(); // giving No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

So when my query_string selects columns of type int or varchar, I'm not facing any problems, but When I'm trying to select columns which are of tyoe uuid, I'm getting the above mentioned exception, probably because it couldn't find the corresponding java mappings for them.

How do I avoid this? Is there anyway I can add the mappings explicitly for the query to pick up for these column types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was getting these errors because, some of the columns I was selecting was of type uuid in postgres. I guess they couldn't be mapped to an appropriate data type like how varchar was being mapped to string. So I changed my sql query to cast the column to varchar. As in, say my column c1 in table t1 was of type uuid, then I'm doing this in my sql query:

```
SELECT CAST(t1.c1 AS VARCHAR) .....REST_OF_THE_QUERY
```

So, this'll result in my column values to be returned as varchar, which're then treated as strings.

Not sure if there's any alternative, but this's the best I could come up with. If anyone knows any better approach, they can share here.

Answer (score 2):

As per error message uuid column type cannot be mapped to a database type by hibernate. In it could be the `java.util.UUID` type.

So Just apply the annotation `@Type(type="uuid-char")` for your UUID type.

Also you can check [HERE](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) the required type for you fields in Hibernate and can use accordingly.

Comment: Where do I apply the annotation?

Comment: in your entity class... UUID field level

Comment: Yea, but I can't an entity class for this purpose as my query is using a join for this and it involves 2 entities.